# Coker of map $\alpha_1(11)^*\oplus \alpha_2(11)^*$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

How to calculate the 3-local Coker of map $\pi_{11}(Sp(3))\overset{{\alpha_1(11)}^* \oplus {\alpha_2(11)}^*}\longrightarrow \pi_{14}(Sp(3))\oplus \pi_{18}(Sp(3))$?
where $\pi_{11}(Sp(3))\cong \mathbb{Z}$ , $\pi_{14}(Sp(3))\cong \mathbb{Z}_9$ and $\pi_{18}(Sp(3))\cong \mathbb{Z}_{27}$. That is we need to 3-local Coker of the map
$\mathbb{Z} \overset{{\alpha_1(11)}^* \oplus {\alpha_2(11)}^*}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_9\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{27}$.
Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: What's that map? How is it defined?

Comment: The maps $\alpha_1(11)^*: \pi_{11}(Sp(3))\rightarrow \pi_{14}(Sp(3)) $ and $\alpha_2(11)^*: \pi_{11}(Sp(3))\rightarrow \pi_{18}(Sp(3)) $ are define naturality, where $\alpha_1(11): S^{14}\rightarrow S^{11}$ and $\alpha_2(11): S^{18}\rightarrow S^{11}$ are Toda notations.

Comment: Where can one find the definitions of Toda notations?

Comment: COMPOSITION METHODS IN HOMOTOPY GROUPS
OF SPHERES, BY Hirosi Toda PRINCETON, NEW JERSEY
PRINCETON UNIVERSITY PRESS
1962